# Magento 2 Images Not Showing in FTP under /pub/static/frontend/..../images

Tags: magento2

I ran a GTMetrix performance check on one of my client websites

> Losslessly compressing https://www.buzzyblends.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/buzzy/default/en_GB/images/healthy.jpg could save 15.9KiB (27% reduction). See optimized version.
>   Losslessly compressing https://www.buzzyblends.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/buzzy/default/en_GB/images/linkedin.jpg could save 12.4KiB (81% reduction). See optimized version.

and similar findings under the /pub/static/frontend/buzzy/default/en_GB/images folder.

But when I traversed the folders via FTP, the images were not present on the folder. The image names appeared under the directory but all the files were zero kb.

Am I looking at the wrong place to download the original images and optimise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the images in your custom theme at `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/web/images/` then download the original images and optimize it and upload as the same path then deploy your theme below command.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Is a manual deploy necessary or will it auto-deploy eventually?

Comment: yes manual deploy necessary using CLI Command line